# find by regular expression with Casbah

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah, mongodb-scala

how to use regular expressions at `Collection#find(/* HERE */)` like:

```
val coll = MongoConnection()("foo")("bar")
for(x <- coll.find("name" -> ".*son$".r)) {
   // some operations...
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are close, you just need to wrap your conditions in a `MongoDBObject()`.

We had to pull out the implicit conversions of `<key> -> <value>` in a bunch of places because they were hard to catch properly and were breaking other code.

They'll probably be back in 2.1.

Do this instead:

```
val coll = MongoConnection()("foo")("bar")
for(x <- coll.find(MongoDBObject("name" -> ".*son$".r))) {
   // some operations...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For adding IGNORECASE above answer will not work by appending "/i" at the end of regex in Scala, Casbah.
For this purpose use:

```
val EmailPattern = Pattern.compile(companyName,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
val q = MongoDBObject("companyName" ->  EmailPattern)
val result = MongoFactory.COLLECTION_NAME.findOne(q)
```